# Is it evident whether I am a masters student or a PhD student just by looking at my transcript?

Tags: phd, masters, transcript-of-records

After I finished the first year in a PhD program, considering that I took the same courses that masters students in the same school take, is there a way other institutions can tell if I am a masters student or a PhD student just by looking at my official transcript?

Comment: Why not get your own copy of your official transcript, and see what it says?

Comment: At least where I am getting a copy of the official transcript is quiet expensive. Unexpectedly expensive infact.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, the name of the degree program that the student is enrolled in is listed on the transcripts. So generally speaking, yes, it is evident whether you are a masters student or a PhD student.